# Permission error when activating activate_this.py file in pipenv environment through app.wsgi

Tags: apache, pipenv

This is last line of error.log

```
[Tue Aug 17 10:58:43.663287 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 9685:tid 140291094402816] [remote 127.0.0.1:40518] PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/not/.local/share/virtualenvs/textapi_flask-mXLf-cmV/bin/activate_this.py'
```

Edit 1:
used `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/textapi_flask`
and
`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/not/.local/share/virtualenvs/textapi_flask-mXLf-cmV/bin`

to change owner but still getting same error

Comment: You forget access code: `sudo chown -R 777 ...` for example

Comment: i am changing the ownership of that directory with chown and already used 777 to change permissions for it but still gives above error. I am new to this pardon me if I am saying anything stupid.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common problem and I struggled to find the answer for at least 2 days. The reason is the mod of the parent directory of this file. Check the executability of every directory above your file by:

```
namei -m /home/not/.local/share/virtualenvs/textapi_flask-mXLf-cmV/bin/activate_this.py
```

Then change the mod of each folder/file which is not executable by for example:

```
chmod 755 /home/not/.local
```